# Connection refused on custom port on Azure linux VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, ports

I have a linux vm on Azure. I opened an inbound rule for port 20212 tcp and furthermore in created a rule in iptables to allow traffic to this port.

But when i do telnet 127.0.0.1 20212 i get a connection refused error and also when i do telnet SERVER-IP 20212 i get the same error. Is there any other step in  need in opening a custom port on Azure VMs

Comment: Please ensure your port 20212 is listening on `tcp`. You could use `netstat -ant|grep 20212`. The result shoud be like as below `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20212              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  `

Comment: According to your description, I guess your app is not running.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 moving pieces to this puzzle:

1. Network Security Group allowing a port
2. Linux VM firewall allowing a port
3. Application that is running and listening on the port

It appears that you are missing the third one.